# Choose Realtime Database Instance when using the Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

Since November 12, 2020 it's [possible to create a firebase database instance in europe](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/11/realtime-database-region-and-api.html).

I have already moved my cloud functions to europe. Now, I want to access the database located in europe within the cloud function. I DO NOT want to install a trigger.

At the moment, I can simply say `admin.database().ref("/SomeLocation");` inside my cloud function code, and it will select the default (US) database. However, since the new European database is in the same project, I'm expecting to be able to use something like `admin.database("europe-west1").ref("/Diagrams");` to reference my EU database.

Extra info. I'm initializing my cloud function with `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);`. However, `admin.initializeApp();` should also work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the database instance when you initialize the Admin SDK, as illustrated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-admin-privileges):

```
admin.initializeApp({
  databaseURL: "https://[databaseName].firebaseio.com"
});
```

Replace databaseName with your unique database instance name.

Comment: Note: European instances have a different URL structure: `"https://<project-id>-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app` (for the default db).

Comment: Thanks, i'll try. 
Will that still work when using the emulators? I assume the emulators would use the `functions.config().firebase` config?

Comment: I don't know.  If it doesn't work, you can file a bug report with the emulator repo.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools